# JTextArea with strange behaviour when resizing the JFrame

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I'm using some `JTextArea` in my Swing application. The surrounded `JScrollPane` is added to a `JPanel` using the `GridBagLayout` manager.

```
// Pseudo Code ----

JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
area.setRows(3);

JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(area);

JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
p.add(sp, new GridBagConstraints(
          0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, WEST, HORIZONTAL, new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4), 0, 0));

// ----------------
```

Everything works fine. No problem at all until I will resize the `JFrame`. Then **both `JTextArea` will collapse to one row**. However there is enough place for at least one of them.

Why the element collapse to one row?
Does anyone know a solution? Has anyone an idea?

Comment: both? I can only find one in your code...

Comment: Yes. I just put an example to this post. It is not my real code. It may irrelevant and I should remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use a `BorderLayout` around my elements, it works.
Pete, MrWiggles, Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is because you have your weighty set to 0 (6th argument to the GridBagConstraints constructor).  You'll need to increase this if you want your component to grow vertically.

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure you are setting the 'preferred size' property on your scrollpane's. I've had strange behavior (panes/fields collapsing/disappearing) when frames and panels get resized when this property is not set.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently where I had two JTextAreas with different GridBagConstraint.weighty values and both were set to GridBagConstraint.fill = BOTH. When I would change the text in the JTextAreas, they would change sizes (which I would expect not to happen if weights and fill values are set). Oddly enough, all I had to do was set a preferred size to the JScrollPanes that surrounded the JTexAreas. The preferred size dimension could be anything, as the "fill = BOTH" caused the preferred size to be ignored, but it did something magical to fix my problem.